# Using an OpenPGP card to authenticate with a public-key in SSH on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, openpgp

I want to use an OpenPGP card to authenticate with a public-key in Secure Shell.

On linux, I know I can authenticate by using gpg-agent. But on Windows, I can't authenticate by using gpg-agent (a part of GPG4WIN)!

So, What is the best way to authenticate when using Cygwin or Putty?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty support had introduced in GnuPG 2.0.21. See following announcement.

http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-July/046947.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.